# Is there any CSS to align a box/element?

Tags: html, css

I've seen people say not to use `<div align="center">Some Text</div>` and `<center>Some Text</center>` because it's outdated but I can't find any CSS to align everything inside an element. The closest thing I've found to it is `text-align: center;` but that just aligns the text, not the elements. Is there any CSS that allows you to align elements?

This is the CSS. The thing that I want to center is `#editor`. It's a `<textarea></textarea>` tag.

```css
@font-face {
 font-family: Bandits;
 src: url("Bandits.ttf");
 font-weight: bold;
}

#editor {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 35px;
 left: 35px;
 width: 800px;
 height: 600px;
 resize: none;
}

#see-result {
 position: absolute;
 top: 276px;
 left: 425px;
 width: 125px;
 letter-spacing: 2.7px;
 font-weight: bold;
 background-color: #888;
 text-align: center;
 padding-top: 6.5px;
 padding-bottom: 6.5px;
 cursor: pointer;
 font-family: Calibri;
} #see-result:hover {
 background-color: #ABABAB;
}

header {
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 65px;
 font-family: Bandits;
 letter-spacing: 2px;
}
```

Comment: Depends on what you're trying to center. https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

Comment: Post the code you're having trouble with. There's no one solution for all possible layouts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To horizontally center a box you need to give it an explicit width and then set its margins to "0 auto":

```css
.container{
    border:solid 2px lightblue;
    width:600px;
    height:400px;
}

.center{
    border:solid 2px red;
    height:200px;

    /*centering CSS*/
    width:200px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="center">
        This box is centereed
    </div>
</div>
```

You can also horizontally align a box by giving it's parent container a text-align value of center and making it display:inline:

```css
.container{
    border:solid 2px lightblue;
    width:600px;
    height:400px;
    text-align:center;
}

.center{
    border:solid 2px red;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
  
    /*Centering CSS*/
    display:inline;
    text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="center">
        This box is centereed
    </div>
</div>
```

Finally, you can use flexbox to horizontally align block containers within their parent:

```css
.container{
    border:solid 2px lightblue;
    width:600px;
    height:400px;
 
    /*Centering CSS*/
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
}

.center{
    border:solid 2px red;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="center">
        This box is centereed
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use css flexbox for vertical and horizontal positionaing here

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```css
.flex-container {
     display: -webkit-flex;
     display: flex;
     width: 450px;
     height: 250px;
     background-color: lightgrey;
     justify-content: center;
     text-align: center;
     align-items: center;
}

.flex-item {
      background-color: cornflowerblue;
      width: 100px;
     height: 100px;
     margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item">flex item 1</div>
   <div class="flex-item">flex item 2</div>
  <div class="flex-item">flex item 3</div> 
</div>
```